# Tutlesim GO2GOAL python code error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried the following code from Turtlesim tutorial (GO TO GOAL):

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
from math import pow, atan2, sqrt



class TurtleBot:


    def __init__(self):
    
        rospy.init_node('turtlebot_controller', anonymous=True)
        self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/turtle1/cmd_vel',Twist, queue_size=10)
        self.pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/turtle1/pose',Pose, self.update_pose)
        self.pose = Pose()
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    
    
    def update_pose(self,data):
        
        self.pose = data
        self.pose.x = round(self.pose.x, 4)
        self.pose.y = round(self.pose.y, 4)
    

    def euclidean_distance(self, goal_pose):

            return sqrt(pow((goal_pose.x - self.pose.x), 2) + pow((goal_pose.y - self.pose.y), 2))
    
    def linear_vel(self, goal_pose, constant = 1.5):
        
        return constant * self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose)
        
    
    def steering_angle(self, goal_pose):
    
        return atan2(goal_pose.y - self.pose.y, goal_pose.x - self.pose.x)
    
    
    def angular_vel(self, goal_pose, constant = 6):
    
        return constant * (self.steering_angle(goal_pose) - self.pose.theta)
    
    
    def move2goal(self):

        goal_pose = Pose()
        
        goal_pose.x = input("Set your x goal: ")
        goal_pose.y = input("Set your y goal: ")
        
        distance_tolerance = input("Set your tolerance: ")
        
        vel_msg = Twist()
        
        while self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose) >= distance_tolerance:
        
            vel_msg.linear.x = self.linear_vel(goal_pose)
            vel_msg.linear.y = 0
            vel_msg.linear.z = 0
            
            vel_msg.angular.x = 0
            vel_msg.angular.y = 0
            vel_msg.angular.z = self.angular_vel(goal_pose)
            
            self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
            
            self.rate.sleep()
            
        vel_msg.linear.x = 0
        vel_msg.linear.z = 0
        self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
        
        rospy.spin()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        x = TurtleBot()
        x.move2goal()
        
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

When i run it, it asks for value of x, value of y and then value of tolerance. But after entering tolerance it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul_pavish/draw_arm/devel/lib/turtle_control/turtle_control_node.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/paul_pavish/draw_arm/src/turtle_control/turtle_control_node.py", line 82, in <module>
    x.move2goal()
  File "/home/paul_pavish/draw_arm/src/turtle_control/turtle_control_node.py", line 57, in move2goal
    while self.euclidean_distance(goal_pose) >= distance_tolerance:
  File "/home/paul_pavish/draw_arm/src/turtle_control/turtle_control_node.py", line 29, in euclidean_distance
    return sqrt(pow((goal_pose.x - self.pose.x), 2) + pow((goal_pose.y - self.pose.y), 2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

I assume that the `goal_pose = Pose()` didn't do it's part.  If yes, then that means that import from a different module from `turtlesim.msg import Pose` didn't work. I tried simple Publisher & Subscriber (it worked) and Turtlesim_teleop_key(it also worked) along with some other customisations on Publisher & Subscriber (worked). Then whats happening here ???

Any suggestions on how to fix this TypeError ?
I tried converting ever pose related object/variable to `float` , and it seems working fine then, but that's not the answer for long run, . Need Help ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Paul Pavish

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364714/tutlesim-go2goal-python-code-error-:-typeerror:-unsupported-operand-type(s)-for--:-%27str%27-and-%27float%27/) by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace

```
goal_pose.x = input("Set your x goal: ")
goal_pose.y = input("Set your y goal: ")
```

with

```
goal_pose.x = float(input("Set your x goal: "))
goal_pose.y = float(input("Set your y goal: "))
```

This should resolve the issue.

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2020-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on 2020-11-04**:
Thanks @skpro19,
Yes it did work . But then what happened to the `goal_pose=Pose()` , why it didn't work? or if this is the actual method for float input, then why is it wrong in the ROS Turtlesim Go To Goal tutorial ?

I'm just trying to understand.

Thanks & Regards
Paul Pavish

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-04**:
I don't think there's an issue with `goal_pose = Pose()`. It is just that the way you were taking the input earlier was causing Python to think that x and y are Strings.